# Zabbix IBM MQM loadable module blocks the ZABBIX Agent service

Tags: module, centos, ibm-mq, zabbix

I'm trying to test ZABBIX's IBM MQ module, all the code is posted on [the ZABBIX share](https://share.zabbix.com/cat-app/queue-managers/ibm-mq-agent-module), but as I'm a newbie and there are no explained steps to do it, I'm stuck.
So I'm working with the sources of ZABBIX 3.4 and headers of MQM 8 trial version (Running on Centos7 64bit).
First of all when I try to Compile the file mq.c there is the variable argc I think it shouldn't be there !! the error was like :

```
[root@osboxes dummy]# make
gcc -fPIC -shared -o mq.so mq.c -I../../../include -I/opt/mqm/inc
mq.c: In function ‘mq_q_depth’:
mq.c:61:9: error: ‘argc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (argc > 1) strncpy(queue, param, (size_t)MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);
         ^
mq.c:61:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each funct                              ion it appears in
make: *** [mq] Error 1
```

I commented this line where there is the argc :

```
if (argc > 1) strncpy(queue, param, (size_t)MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);
```

The compilation succeeded, but when I try to upload the module on the ZABBIX agent configuration, the agent wouldn't start and gave me this error:

```
[root@osboxes dummy]# service zabbix-agent start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start zabbix-agent.service
Job for zabbix-agent.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status zabbix-agent.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


[root@osboxes dummy]# systemctl status zabbix-agent.service
● zabbix-agent.service - Zabbix Agent
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-agent.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: resources) since Fri 2018-03-16 14:35:43 CET; 3s ago
Process: 5069 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd -c $CONFFILE (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 16 14:35:43 osboxes.org systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
Mar 16 14:35:43 osboxes.org systemd[1]: Failed to start Zabbix Agent.
Mar 16 14:35:43 osboxes.org systemd[1]: Unit zabbix-agent.service entered failed state.
Mar 16 14:35:43 osboxes.org systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

[root@osboxes dummy]# journalctl -xe
--
-- The result is failed.
Mar 16 14:36:04 osboxes.org systemd[1]: Unit zabbix-agent.service entered failed state.
Mar 16 14:36:04 osboxes.org systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service failed.
Mar 16 14:36:14 osboxes.org systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service holdoff time over, scheduling resta
Mar 16 14:36:14 osboxes.org systemd[1]: Starting Zabbix Agent...
-- Subject: Unit zabbix-agent.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.or...
--
-- Unit zabbix-agent.service has begun starting up.
Mar 16 14:36:14 osboxes.org systemd[1]: PID file /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid not readable (yet
Mar 16 14:36:14 osboxes.org systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
Mar 16 14:36:14 osboxes.org systemd[1]: Failed to start Zabbix Agent.
-- Subject: Unit zabbix-agent.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.or...
--
-- Unit zabbix-agent.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Mar 16 14:36:14 osboxes.org systemd[1]: Unit zabbix-agent.service entered failed state.
Mar 16 14:36:14 osboxes.org systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service failed.
```

I hope you could give me some help with it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  So whoever wrote the code for Zabbix's mq.c was lazy and copied it from the their qdepth.c example.

> I commented this line where there is the argc :

Bad idea.  It looks like it should be:

```
if (request->nparam == 1) strncpy(queue, param, (size_t)MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);
```

I don't have access to Zabbix's SDK, so it is just a guess.

> Job for zabbix-agent.service failed because a configured resource
>   limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status zabbix-agent.service" and
>   "journalctl -xe" for details.

Well that error message is pretty clear.  It is time to read the docs/manual to find out what are the minimum or recommend resource settings because you clearly do not enough resources to run everything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to add more resources but without success, the weird part that when I execute the code in c, it works. So the problem is happening just after wrapping it within the Zabbix dummy module.